# Dev C++ Crashes on this code

Tags: c++, string, initialization

I have the below code and I have 2 problems, one being that I an error of [Warning] initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast even, I am not able to understand why, the warning shows on the line : *printf("String 1 : %s and Its length is %i \nString 2 : %s and its length is %i\n", strg1, strlen(strg1), strg2, strlen(strg2));*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int strg_len2(char *s);

int main(void)
{
   /*  Declare variables.  */
   char strg1[] = "This is one string ";
   char strg2[] = "and this is a second string";
   char *strg3 = /* allocate memory dynamically */

   /*  Print the strg1, strg2 and their lengths.  */
//   printf("String 1 : %s\nString 2 : %s\n", strg1, strg2);
   printf("String 1 : %s and Its length is %i \nString 2 : %s and its length is %i\n", strg1, strlen(strg1), strg2, strlen(strg2));

   /* Allocate memory for strg3 */
    strg3 = (char*) malloc((strlen(strg1)+strlen(strg2)*sizeof(char)));

   /* Combine the strings (strg1 and strg2) to strg3*/
   strcpy(strg3,strg1);
   strcat(strg3,strg2);

   /*print strg3 and its length */
   printf("%s, now length of string 3 is : %i\n", strg3, strlen(strg3));

   /* strncat() - add only 10 char of strg2 to strg1 and store them into strg3 */
    printf("\nContatanation of String 1 And 10 characters of string 2 : %s", strncat(strg1, strg2,10));
    strg3 = strncat(strg1, strg2,10);
   /*print strg3 and its length */
    printf("%s\t%i", strg3, strlen(strg3));

} /*end main()*/
```

The second error is when I have combined 2 strings into the third one, if I print the 3rd is string there is error as in the image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRK03.png)

This part : *printf("%s, now length of string 3 is : %i\n", strg3, strlen(strg3));*

Comment: And once you get this to work, ditch it and use `std::string`.  After all, this is supposed to be C++, not C.

Comment: you need to case `(int)strlen(X)` when using that in `printf`, because `%i` is the format specifier for `int`, not `size_t`

Comment: `strncat(strg1, strg2,10)` writes out of bounds of `strg1`

Answer (score 1):

Since the strg3 declaration is not closed with a semicolon, it says:

```
char *strg3 = printf("String 1 : %s and Its length is %i \nString 2 : %s and its length is %i\n", strg1, strlen(strg1), strg2, strlen(strg2));
```

Second issue is that the strg3 allocation is one byte (or actually one size(char)) short:

```
strg3 = (char*) malloc((strlen(strg1)+strlen(strg2)*sizeof(char)));
```

This does not include space for the '\0' terminator. The following strcat will overwrite the allocated memory buffer.

Comment: I apologise for editing your answer - our answers were quite similar and I intended to edit mine. When I realised my mistake, I was not able to rollback my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semicolon after `char *strg3 =`. The compiler ignores the comments and looks for what you're trying to assign to `strg3`. It finds the `printf` call and assigns the result of that. The `printf` returns an `int` (which is the number of characters printed). So compiler thinks you are assigning an `int` to `char* strg3`. Just declare it without assigning anything eg `char *strg3;`

You need to allocate one more char to `strg3` to hold the 2 other strings.

```
strg3 = (char*) malloc( (strlen(strg1)+strlen(strg2) + 1) *sizeof(char));
```

C-style strings need space for an extra `\0` at the end. The `strcat` will add the `\0` but that will then write over memory that does not belong to `strg3` with possibly disastrous results like writing over the return address of the function.

Comment: By this logic the `+1` should be inside the parentheses with the `strlen` calls (although it's moot because `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`)

Comment: Yes, it did look a bit odd - edited it to be consistent. I thought it would stand out better if the `+1` was right at the end. I debated about removing `sizeof(char)` but I'm not sure of the etiquette for tidying up OP's code and decided to only change what was necessary for code to wqrk.